# Escape single quote in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a function as:

```
function makeTitleEditable($titleContainer){
        var defaultValue = $titleContainer.text().replace("'","\\'");
        $titleContainer.replaceWith("<input id='poll_title' name='poll[title]' value='" + defaultValue +"' type='text'>");
      }
```

Now the problem was I still can't escape the single quote. For example, if

```
$titleContainer.text() => I'm lucky

console.log("<input id='poll_title' name='poll[title]' value='" + defaultValue +"' type='text'>") => <input id='poll_title' name='poll[title]' value='I\'m lucky!' type='text'>
```

which would generate DOM with value "I" rather than "I'm lucky". How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why don´t you using double quotes for your attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery to set the value;

```
function makeTitleEditable($titleContainer){
    $titleContainer.replaceWith(
       $("<input id='poll_title' name='poll[title]' type='text'>").val($titleContainer.text())
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Of course the quick fix is simply to replace `"'"` with `"\'"` although that really isn't scalable on copy-and-paste-type basis.
Better would be via a regex, such as:

```
var badString = "Visit John's Site!!!";
var goodString = badString.replace(/'/g, "\'");
```

Remember though that they'll then show up server-side or even in subsequent function calls as simple apostrophes again, so if you're planning to pass them around between different functions, another solution might be preferable:

```
var badString = "Visit John's Site!!!";
var goodString = badString.replace(/'/g, "\x27");
```

This is the standard Unicode character for an apostrophe. This won't  necessarily avoid any subsequent function calls giving a problem, but it means the string won't have to be decoded.